# Htmlescape'ing in flair alt text

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, encoding

A minor bug: the alt text of flairs is encoded twice. For example, the `á` in my unfortunate username is rendered as `&amp;#225;`

[image]

You see, first the `SáT` is escaped as `S&#225;T`, then it's escaped again, producing `S&amp;#225;T`. It affects all sites, and the combined flair as well.

Sure, it's nothing terrible, but I figured it doesn't hurt to report it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.